# Serial numbering of Tickets for public service in an office where we have 15 different departments

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am trying to create a database for an office which have 15 different departments, trying to issue tickets for public who access 15 different departments, I need to start the serial numbering for each department separately! is it possible to have just a single table? or do I have to have separate table for each department?   and also the ticket numbers table must be reset everyday at midnight and the very next day, Ticket numbers for each and every department should be started from ticket number 1!

Please help me guys! You guys are best helper for a fresher like me

Thank you

Comment: I've never met one public service (or private) department that can successfully deal with all tickets in a day. Welcome to SO, a help site. Start by including what you have tried and for which MySQL version.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I'm using Xampp app locally, version: 10.4.8-MariaDB, Actually, I had developed a system to register all public who access the office at the front desk, That's working fine, Now, I'm planning to issue a service request ticket with a serial number to guide public to go and their job done at the related department!

Comment: Why is it a requirement that the ticket numbers be recycled every day?

Comment: as that records is no more needed for next day as its just a token number to get their service done in a serial number based like first in, first served.  also for next day, I need to start the serial number to be started from number one,  this is how its been designed in few ministries of public services

Answer (score 1):

you can do in a single table but in that case you will not have to make any primary key or unique key ..thats not a proper way so you should create two separate table one for department and second for ticket_issue and in 2nd table take dpartment_id as foreign key and a separate field for serial number(Note:don't use id as serial number)

to generate serial number get previous serial number from 2nd table for current department and increase 1 on them for next

and for clear data every night you can run a chron job